# In case of batch read in JDBC using setFetchSize, if we apply timeout to statement then is it batch level timeout?

Tags: jdbc

```
Statement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BOOKS");
statement.setFetchSize(100);
statement.setQueryTimeout(10);//Timeout of 10 seconds
```

here is the timeout for per batch or total records to be fetched?

Comment: It is a timeout on the query, which means the time elapsed between the request and the first response.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Not necessarily. Query timeouts in JDBC are largely driver/database specific.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC API documentation of [`Statement.setQueryTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)) says:

> Sets the number of seconds the driver will wait for a Statement object
> to execute to the given number of seconds. By default there is no
> limit on the amount of time allowed for a running statement to
> complete. If the limit is exceeded, an `SQLTimeoutException` is
> thrown. A JDBC driver must apply this limit to the `execute`,
> `executeQuery` and `executeUpdate` methods.
>
> **Note**: JDBC driver implementations may also apply this limit to `ResultSet` methods (consult your driver vendor documentation for
> details).
>
> **Note**: In the case of `Statement` batching, it is implementation defined as to whether the time-out is applied to individual SQL
> commands added via the `addBatch` method or to the entire batch of SQL
> commands invoked by the `executeBatch` method (consult your driver
> vendor documentation for details).

In other words, this will depend on the database and driver you use.

Some drivers might apply it to execute only, and fetching rows after execute might not be subject to the timeout, some might apply it to individual fetches triggered by `ResultSet.next()` as well, and yet others might even use the wall clock time since query execution started and forcibly close the cursor if query execution and fetching and processing rows takes longer than the specified timeout (which could trigger the timeout even if the server is quick to respond, but it is the client that is taking a long time to process the entire result set).